# register broadcastReceiver in Service

Tags: android

I have problem with my app, it takes data from the server and decided when to remind, I did mistake when realise this alhoritm in service because in sleeping mode service is stopping, I need replace this with Alarm but I have a lot of variables in the service and it is problem to send them to AlarmReceiver class, I read about inner class but I can't register it in the manifest it can be only static,I tryed to use register receiver but it is not working what I do wrong with it?

```
public  class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private String text;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();
        Autobus66Service.UpdatePassages();
        wl.release();
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context,String text){
        this.text = text;
        AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 30 * 1, pi);
    }

    public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(sender);
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.d("service onCreate", MainActivity.TAG);
    handler = new Handler();
    intent = new Intent(AppNames.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    ...

    alarm = new AlarmReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter= new IntentFilter();
    registerReceiver(alarm,filter);

}


@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.d("service onStart", MainActivity.TAG);

    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
    handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000);
    createNotification();
    alarm.SetAlarm(this,"Some text");

}
```

and in AndroidManifest it looks like:

```
  <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name="com.autobus66.autobus66.service.Autobus66Service$AlarmReceiver">

    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be only

```
public static class AlarmReceiver
```

and I believe it should be referenced as

```
android:name="com.autobus66.autobus66.service.Autobus66Service.AlarmReceiver"
```

***static*** because an instance of inner class has an implicit reference to the containing instance of the containing class. You cannot create a non-static instance of the inner class outside of the instance methods of the containing class because java needs a pointer to that instance of containing class.

This means that you have to find some way to keep the state of your application. Note also that any  process may be killed and restarted (including both services and activities) and the apps should be written so that killing the process does not lead to data loss. (I do not say it is good, I say it is so.)